# Oracle date conversion outputs 2000s instead of required 1990s

Tags: sql, oracle, date

During execution of below query, the output is **2090**.

```
select to_char(to_date('10-OCT-90', 'DD-MON-YY'), 'YYYY') from dual;
```

Required output is **1990**, the date in the snippet is Birth Date.

**EDIT:**
The input date is fetched from a table, so the date is in DD-MON-YY format.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: Removed MySQL, by going through the title!

Comment: Thanks @RahulTripathi

Comment: It could also be 1890. Many people were born that year too.

Comment: Btw, `The input date is fetched from a table, so the date is in DD-MON-YY format` - input date or input string? What type of column you're trying to convert to `YYYY` format?

Comment: Unbelievable, people still fall into the **Y2K** bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For alternative resolving the double-digit years in strings, Oracle has [the `RR` format element](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#i116004). Thus, your query would be

```
select to_char(to_date('10-OCT-90', 'DD-MON-RR'), 'YYYY') from dual;
```

From the referenced Oracle doc:

> The RR datetime format element is similar to the YY datetime format element, but it provides additional flexibility for storing date values in other centuries. The RR datetime format element lets you store 20th century dates in the 21st century by specifying only the last two digits of the year.

Comment: What's the result of to_char(to_date('07-NOV-15', 'DD-MON-RR'), 'YYYY')? Today, and tomorrow?

Comment: Result is 2015... sick.

Answer (score 2):

Use RR instead of YY. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00215

Answer (score 2):

Try to use RR like this:

```
select to_char(to_date('10-OCT-90', 'DD-MON-RR'), 'YYYY') from dual;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/10211)**

Also note that you should store the dates in YYYY format as it will be confusing to make the correct assumption as to the birth year is in 2000 or 1900 or 1800 or... ;)

The [Oracle docs](http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-dev-l/difference-between-yyyy-and-rrrr-format-519496#M519525) says:

> YY allows you to retrieve just two digits of a year, for example, the
>   99 in 1999. The other digits (19) are automatically assigned to the
>   current century. RR converts two-digit years into four-digit years by
>   rounding.
>
> 50-99 are stored as 1950-1999, and dates ending in 00-49 are stored as
>   2000-2049. RRRR accepts a four-digit input (although not required),
>   and converts two-digit dates as RR does. YYYY accepts 4-digit inputs
>   butdoesn't do any date converting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for my Date column (DOB) if DOB is 27-08-1947. I use below conversion format to get correct year to calculate age.

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DOB,'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')

TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DOB,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) TODAY,
TO_DATE(BIRTH_DATE,'DD-MON-RR') DOB,
BIRTH_DATE
FROM TM_DM_CLIENT
WHERE CLIENT_NO IN ('22943179')
```

**output**

```
Today   DOB BIRTH_DATE
10/1/2019   1/1/2041    1/1/1941
```